# Randomize javascript audio variable on music finish

Tags: javascript, html

I have a start and stop buttons and I'm trying to randomize the song that will be played next if the start button is just pressed 1 time, but I keep getting the same music to be played over and over.

It randomizes fine if I press start, stop and start again, but not when the music finishes by herself - can somebody tell me what is wrong with the code?

```
var sounds = [
        "sounds/royksopp.mp3",
        "sounds/9thwonder.mp3",
        "sounds/thisbeat.mp3",
        "sounds/mosdef.mp3",
        "sounds/bewater.mp3",
        "sounds/boutdre.mp3",
        "sounds/masterflash.mp3",
        "sounds/2ep.mp3",
        "sounds/drewestcoast.mp3",
        "sounds/poetry.mp3",
        "sounds/mfdoom.mp3",
        "sounds/imnot.mp3",
        "sounds/jamba.mp3",
        "sounds/meetyour.mp3",
        "sounds/popyacork.mp3",
        "sounds/dreams.mp3",
        "sounds/unders.mp3",
        "sounds/oizo.mp3",
    ];

function StartOrStop(audioFile) {
    srcAudio = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length)];
    var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    audie.addEventListener('ended', function() {
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.play();
    }, false);

    if (audie.paused == false) {
        audie.pause();
    } else {
        audie.src = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length)];
        audie.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly because you just do `this.play();` when ended and no randomising there

Comment: `audie.addEventListener('ended', function() {
   this.currentTime = 0; this.src = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length)];
   this.play();}, false);`

Answer (score 0):

Your logic could definitely work but it might get a bit complicated. Here is what I would recommend you to do:

```js
document.getElementById("myAudio").addEventListener("ended", EndedEventHandler);

.
.
.

function Start(audioFile) {
  var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");
  audie.play();
}

function Stop() {
  var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");
  audie.pause();
}

function EndedEventHandler() {
  var audioFile = GetRandomAudioFile();
  Start(audioFile);
}

function GetRandomAudioFile() {
  return sounds[Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length)];
}
```